# Проблема с iframe в Opera

Tags: opera, javascript, php, youtube-api

Добрый день. Используется загрузка видео в определенный Youtube-канал на самом сайте. При помощи JS создается **форма** и **iframe (name="myframe")**, для формы указываю через атрибут **target** этот созданный **iframe**. В самом Youtube API после загрузки видео, делается редирект на *url* содержащий *GET* параметры **status** и **id**:

```
http://testik.ru/upload.php?status=200&id=[id_video]
```

В Chrome и Firefox я могу получить нужный мне адрес из **iframe**:

```
window.frames['myframe'].location.href
```

А Opera всегда возвращает *about:blank*, и к тому же не отображает содержимое iframe.. Т.е. само видео загружено, а получить **корректный ID** видео я не могу.

Сейчас более подробно опишу, как я создаю форму и фрейм:

```
//Ответ от Youtube-API
json = {
    url: [url_from_youtube]?nexturl=[my_url],
    token: [access_token_from_youtube]
}

var form = $('<form action="' + json.url + '" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">');
form.attr('id', 'iform');
form.appendTo(document.body);
form.css({
    'position': 'absolute',
    'top': '-50%',
    'left': '-50%'
});

var file = $('#' + fileId);
file.attr('name', 'file');
file.appendTo(form);
var hidden = $('<input type="hidden" name="token" value="' + json.token + '">');
hidden.appendTo(form);

var iframe = $('<iframe>');
iframe.css({
    'position': 'fixed',
    'top': '50%',
    'left': '50%',
});
iframe.attr('name', 'iyoutube');
frame.attr('id', 'iyoutube');
iframe.appendTo(document.body);

form.attr('target', 'iyoutube');
form.submit();

iframe.load(function() {
var uri = window.frames['iyoutube'].location.href;
    console.log(uri); // Opera return 'about:blank'
});
```

Извините, может очень глупый вопрос, все время сижу только Chrome.. Можно ли как-то решить проблему с Оперой?

Спасибо!!!

Comment: Нужно просто вытянуть src фрейма?Не совсем понял задачу...

Comment: не используйте фреймы.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте `window.frames['myframe'].window.location.href`, а вообще пример бы.